# HP PL580 gen7 - HP SAS 1,2TB 10K SAS 6G SFF DP is stuck in case

Tags: hp-proliant, sas, hotswap

that's maybe quite a stupid question, but without finding any solution, I have to ask it.

I got an old HP PL580 gen7 together with the 2 HP SAS 1.2TB 10K SAS 6G Harddisks(allready mounted in a cage)

So I basicly pushed both HDDs into slot 1 und 2 without any problem. Anyhow, the harddisks are not detected. So I wanted to Test it with a normal SATA HDD.

How can I remove them? Pushing the red/purple ejector buttons like I did before I pushed them in doesn't help. The little black lever that should be come a bit outside doesn't move a bit. Also the Status Lights on the HDD doesnt show anything.

Am I doing something wrong? Or can it happen that they HDD get locked/stuck in the Server?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try harder.

[**Here's how you remove an HP hot-swap disk.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqY7B9PMn_4)

As for the disks, you still need to configure them before you can use them. That can be done in the BIOS configuration utility.

Comment: Thanks for the video, but the cage looks different, like here:

http://www.gekko-computer.de/HP-Renew/HP_SAS-Festplatte_12TB_10k_SAS_6G_SFF_DP_718162-B21_RENEW_i199_14334_0.htm

Comment: @Vamiris Push the button and keep it push, and try to open the black lever with a flat screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a few of those 2.5" HP hotswap drives get stuck inside servers.  What happens is those metal "fingers" on the drive tray that are supposed to keep the drive in place will sometimes become lodged or bent backwards.

Bottom line: pull harder - the worst you will do is bend or break those little metal fingers.  The plastic carrier is stronger than those so they will go first.  There is no active locking mechanism or anything in these servers so don't be afraid of breaking something internal.

Comment: Hi Chris, regarding ewwhite answer, does your hotswaps look like this?

http://www.gekko-computer.de/HP-Renew/HP_SAS-Festplatte_12TB_10k_SAS_6G_SFF_DP_718162-B21_RENEW_i199_14334_0.htm